# Как удалить все, что после последнего входа символа “/” в строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Разработать скрипт с использованием регулярного выражения для формирования текущего пути к файлу из адреса страницы (вместо имени файла с расширением .asp поставить /). Например, вместо ggg/gl/h.asp должно стать ggg/gl/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\w\.(.*)/` так можно.. главное чтоб в пути больше нигде точки не использовались

ну или так(если могут точки быть):

`/\/\w\.(.*)$/`.. но тут будет находить последний слэш - тогда в конец вручную его добавлять еще

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое)